Avoiding accidental execution of python scripts as bash scripts
I like to run my python scripts directly in bash like so
$ ./script.py

But sometimes I forget the shebang line #!/usr/bin/env python3, and it has the potential to overwrite a file named np if the script has import numpy as np (and if you click a few times when the ImageMagick import command is run).
What can I do to avoid such accidental execution of python scripts as bash scripts? Is there a way to block bash from executing a script that has an extension ".py" as a bash script?

if __name__=="__main__" clause to not have any top level executable code? Don't run as ./script.py and use python script.py instead?

Such a vague question. What constraints do you have? Possible answer: you can leave your computer turned off. [ask]

Computers do what you tell them to. If you're making mistakes and do things you didn't want to, there's not all that much the computer will do to protect you from yourself. Just gotta pay more attention.

@deceze I'm sure people have been bugged by this problem before, and it's good to protect against unintentional mistakes. If not, why is "set -e" a recommended option in bash scripts? also, why have the "noclobber" option, and alias rm="rm -i"? There are just different levels of safety that people tolerate.

A solution would require some hook that intercepts any and all invocations of executables, and inspects them for their file extension and whether they have an appropriate shebang line. I'm not sure such a hook exists (but it might, wouldn't be surprised if it did), but even if it did, that seems like a lot of hassle to deal with your own forgetfulness, and will probably have side effects in other situations.

Use an editor that automatically adds #!/usr/bin/env python3 to any new python file (like most allow already). Don't remove that line.

It's a strange question for sure, but I found it perfectly reasonable. In a world where somebody implemented sl to catch ls typos, this is almost a good idea.

All *.py  file in current dir, that not begin by a shebang: find . -type f -name '*.py' -exec sed -sne '1{\,^#!,!F}' {} +

You can trap the "DEBUG" signal to inspect the command before execution. Then a simple extension check can block .py files but nothing else. You can also test the first line with head -n1 to see if it's the shebang.
Here's a proof of concept:
shopt -s extdebug; stop_cmd () {
    [ -n "$COMP_LINE" ] && return  # not needed for completion
    [ "$BASH_COMMAND" = "$PROMPT_COMMAND" ] && return # not needed for prompt
    local this_command=$BASH_COMMAND;
    if [[ $this_command == *.py ]] && [[ "$(head -n 1 $this_command)" != '#!"* ]]; then
        echo "Blocking execution of Python script without shebang: $this_command"
        return 1
    else
        return 0
    fi
};
trap 'stop_cmd' DEBUG


I think OP wants to block execution only if they forgot to add a shebang line, not generally…

@deceze I think you're right, but this solution can possibly be adapted to do what I want

Good point, I've edited the answer to check for the shebang too.

I'd not disable other combinations of #! /usr/bin/python, etc., but instead probably just check to see if the first line starts with #!. That will handle most of the cases

hmm, but I realised your hook wouldn't catch if I have arguments to my script
